# How to get the pieces together so that Ctrl + L really selects the whole object?

Tags: edges

Although this is a single object, edges that should be connected to each other are not connected. No idea why. I made the selection on the pictures with Ctrl + L.

Now my question is how to get the pieces together so that Ctrl + L really selects the whole object, at best without compromising the quality.[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: if you do a alt M > Merge Distance, and play with distance value, it will merge the two meshes, but there will be a lot of faces overlapping and holes

Comment: Ctrl+L selects all connected verts so obviously you model has multiple parts...

Answer (score 2):

There is no secret magic way to do this. You need join the parts to a single mesh by merging or connecting vertices, filling gaps with faces and other modelling techniques.

If you go to edit mode, select some vertices and hit <kbd>m</kbd> you will get the most useful Merge menu:

[image]

For this mesh merging by distance is not going to work, because the vertices that you need merged are not any closer to each other than vertices you do not need to merge, so you need to select them a couple at a time and decide how you want to merge them in each specific case.

Repeat Last function - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - might be useful here since there are a lot of vertices to merge. You might also want to use some other modelling functions like Fill <kbd>F</kbd>.

It might seem at first like this is loads of work, but actually it's only a few minutes to fix this mess it's just not the most fun job to do.

Comment: if you turn on snapping to vertex, you can save yourself a lot of m pressing

Comment: What snapping? I am not recommending to move them and then merge by distance. The idea is to select and merge with M->L or M->C  or M->A... What does snapping have to do with any of this?